# Call for translation method on Moses as a service using xml-rpc fails

Tags: xml, xml-rpc, machine-translation, moses

I am facing an exception calling moses (Statistical Machine Translation) as a service with xmlrpc installed. I firstly open a port to the Moses server

```
--Listening on port 8082
```

but the main problem is when I send a rest request with an xml as body parameter.

```
<methodCall>
<methodName>translate</methodName>
<params>
<param>
<value>
<array>
<data>
<value>
<array>
<data>
<value>
<string>struct</string>
</value>
<value>
<string>struct</string>
</value>
</data>
</array>
</value>
</data>
</array>
</value>
</param>
</params>
</methodCall>
```

When I execute it as a POST request on http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8082/RPC2

I notice that service on port fails with exception "terminate called after throwing an instance of 'xmlrpc_c::fault'
Aborted
"

I think the main problem is with xml body structure but I cannot find any documentation on the web for translate method. Any suggestions? Thank you.

UPDATE

Note that if I open a port with setting

```
--threads all
```

I never get response back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A working approach but may not the most clean and safe, is calling a python client from c# or java since does not exists library on nuget for doing this work.

```
ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();

            start.FileName = "C:\\python\\python.exe";

            start.Arguments = $"C:\\python27\\client.py {word}";

            start.UseShellExecute = false; // Do not use OS shell

            start.CreateNoWindow = true; // We don't need new window

            start.RedirectStandardOutput = true; // Any output, generated by application will be redirected back

            start.RedirectStandardError = true; // Any error in standard output will be redirected back (for example exceptions)

            using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                {
                    string stderr = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd(); // Here are the exceptions from our Python script

                    string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

                    string result = reader.ReadToEnd(); // Here is the result of StdOut(for example: print "test")
                }
            }
```

and client is something like that [client.py](https://github.com/moses-smt/mosesdecoder/blob/master/contrib/server/client.py)